# Adding pictures to Carousel from your own computer in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications, carousel, vuetify.js

I have a Carousel with some pics. I can use URL link to show the pics but when I want to show pics that are stored in my computer instead of the URL it doesn't show the pictures. What's the way to add a picture to your Carousel from your own computer?

Here is the Code:

```
<template>
<div class="caro">

 <v-carousel >
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
  >

    <div class="text-xs-center">
    </div>

  </v-carousel-item>
 </v-carousel>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data () {
  return {
    items: [
      {
        id: 'rack', src: 'https://logisticpackaging.com/CrXBdba4vG7B2k/wPHm6Sft56fw2V/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/pcb-racking-system5.jpg', title:'Rack Section'
      },
      {
        id: 'subrack', src: '../assets/Parts.jpg' , title: 'Subrack Section'
      },

      {
        id: 'parts', src: '../Hasan.jpg' , title: 'Parts Section'
      },
      {
        id: 'admin', src: 'https://d15shllkswkct0.cloudfront.net/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/Transactional-Database.jpg' , title: 'Database Section'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my example the "rack" and "admin" section do have pictures since they get it from internet. But "parts" and "subrack" don't have pictures since I'm trying to use my own computer's pictures.

Comment: Remember that the path needs to be relative to your html file, not your js file. Maybe the issue lies there? Is the path valid when you check with dev tools?

Comment: I don't have dev tools but it tells me that it cannot get the pic!
Parts.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8083/en/src/assets/Parts.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Every browser has dev tools built in, you just need to press f12 to access it. 'en/src/assets/Parts.jpg' is the picture really in this path?

Comment: Yes it is:

https://imgur.com/J20ha6o

Comment: Which folder is your view's html file in? The link above you posted says 'en/src/...' Does the image get copied to your en folder?

Comment: I just realized that 'en' was extra. I dunno how it got there. Thanks it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running with npm in dev mode or Build? I have a folder called public, i put all my images / svg etc in folders in this public folder, because webpack will build this folder with the vue code.

So as source i use `src="img/brand/logo.svg"`

Except when you dont use webpack and a vue build template, i wouldnt recommend placing images elsewhere than in the public folder. This folder is easy to copy and most likely will be copied by webpack, so you can upload everything in the `dist` folder.

Answer (score 0):

the two photos you are trying to render in the carousel are coming from two different sources, there is nothing wrong with the code, double check the photo source and confirm that the photo extension in the code matches the photo extension in the source folder

Answer (score 0):

Although the Vue loader automatically converts relative paths to required functions, this is not the case with custom components. You can fix this problem by using **require**.
If you change the `items` array format, the problem will be fixed:

```
<script>
export default {
 data () {
  return {
   items: [
      {
        id: 'subrack', src:  require('../assets/Parts.jpg') , title: 'Subrack Section'
      },

      {
        id: 'parts', src:require( '../Hasan.jpg'), title: 'Parts Section'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```